# React Native or Kotlin which is better for cross-platform development?

Tags: react-native, kotlin, cross-platform

I am a react native developer and I really like it for cross-platform development. but I recently heard that kotlin is the future of cross-platform development. I thought I would get better explanation of this in stackoverflow because I have not seen anyone in my circle using kotlin for ios development although I know the fact that kotlin is the first choice when it comes to native development but didn't about its ability of cross-platform development. So should I start learning it with the intention of cross-platform development?

Answer (score 1):

the react-native is good for cross-platform development, especially in the business app. Kotlin is good for the cross-platform library, especially the native
library. because it can compile into java and swift. such as your company's own
network library, log library. I suggest you learn to react-native